# Yum: What is the @shortname for a Package Group?

Tags: redhat, yum

I am creating a kickstart file, and I want to install certain Package Groups in the %packages section. I prefer to install Package Groups, and therefore use the @packagegroup syntax:

```
%packages
@Base
@Core
@Perl
```

I need to find the correct group package name which is compatible with Kickstart/Anaconda, but Kickstart only seems to recognize certain abbreviated names for a package group. For example '@Directory Server' doesn't work, but something like '@Directory' might work.

The problem is that the abbreviated package group (e.g. '@shortname') is cryptic and hard to find. How can I see which @shortname corresponds with a Yum package group?

For example, the following Yum command will provide a description and package list of a package group:

```
$ yum groupinfo \* |head -30
Loaded plugins: changelog, downloadonly, fastestmirror, filter-data, list-data,
              : security
Setting up Group Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * sl: ftp1.scientificlinux.org
 * sl-security: ftp1.scientificlinux.org

Group: Directory Server
 Description: Machine and user identity servers.
 Optional Packages:
   krb5-server
   krb5-server-ldap
   migrationtools
   openldap-servers
   samba
   ypserv
...
```

However, referring to the package group `@Directory Server` in my Kickstart file results in an error (Cannot find group `Directory Server`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Group-Id:

is what you are looking for.

```
sudo yum -v groupinfo "Directory Server"
```

should show you that.

Answer (score 1):

To confirm the item above, the Group-Id: is what shows the short name.
Thanks for posting this and the previous answer. I was looking for the exact same thing.

Kickstart shortname for the package group does not match the yum groupinfo name.

When running the yum -v groupinfo "Group" you can see both.

```
yum -v groupinfo "Graphical Administration Tools"

Group: Graphical Administration Tools
Group-Id: graphical-admin-tools

yum -v groupinfo "Directory Server"
Group: Directory Server
Group-Id: directory-server
```

This test was performed on RHEL 6.3 Workstation

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get the group-id is looking on the iso image from rhel or centos:

mount -t iso9660 -o loop /path/to/[rhel|centos].iso /mount/point

cd /mount/point/

> find  -name "*comps*.xml"  -exec grep groupid {} \; | awk -F"groupid"
>   '{print $2}' | tr -d "</>" | sort | uniq